# Determine Cause of Crash

Tags: ios, crash, symbolicatecrash, crash-log

My app uses Parse.  It puts all objects from class of 'Prayers' into a TableView.  When it loads, it remembers all previously loaded items, searches for new ones.  Starting today, it began crashing when a new item was added.  My crash log looks like this, any thoughts?:

```
Date/Time:           2015-02-13 14:13:25.028 -0600
Launch Time:         2015-02-13 14:13:23.173 -0600
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.3 (12B466)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x185ce259c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1964340e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x185bc762c -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 264
3   iPrayed                         0x1000227a4 0x100014000 + 59300
4   UIKit                           0x18a5a9b7c __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 500
5   UIKit                           0x18a56b9bc -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 3872
6   UIKit                           0x18a56dc10 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 112
7   UIKit                           0x18a56db4c -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 156
8   UIKit                           0x18a56d498 -[UITableView reloadData] + 1304
9   iPrayed                         0x100091730 0x100014000 + 513840
10  iPrayed                         0x1000c9370 0x100014000 + 742256
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x196a793ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x196a7936c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x196a7d980 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 932
14  CoreFoundation                  0x185c99fa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
15  CoreFoundation                  0x185c9804c __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
16  CoreFoundation                  0x185bc50a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
17  GraphicsServices                0x18ed5f5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
18  UIKit                           0x18a4f6aa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
19  iPrayed                         0x1000515e4 0x100014000 + 251364
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x196aa2a08 start + 4
```

Comment: You will need to symbolicate the crash first.The reason in this line - 

3   iPrayed                         0x1000227a4 0x100014000 + 59300

Comment: Not sure exactly how to do that.  I synced my phone, went to Library->Logs->CrashReporter->Mobile and found it, opened up Xcode, Windows ->Devices->This Device, and drug the .crash file into the window, and that is what it showed.

Comment: Refer this link to symbolicate the crash report.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010303/symbolicate-crash-in-ios8-with-xcode-6-1

Comment: Found it @Sandy thanks!  The question for why it is crashing is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510205/parse-pagination-not-working if you want to tackle

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines seem to indicate that your crash is caused by an attempt to access a non-existant index of your array:

> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1964340e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
>   2   CoreFoundation                  0x185bc762c -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 264

If you want any further help, I'd recommend posting the content of your table view methods.