# Understanding the crash reports

Tags: ios

I downloaded a crash log from Xcode (in organizer window) then I symbolicated it with this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988585/1270400

Here my crash log:

```
 Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             Ribony [240]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0FEE0ECC-E7BD-4C72-B0DF-4B699BDA7C42/Ribony.app/Ribony
Identifier:          com.impact.ribony
Version:             24 (3.0.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.impact.ribony [372]


Date/Time:           2016-10-14 19:28:29.1948 +0300
Launch Time:         2016-10-14 19:28:20.2985 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18c1541c0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18ab8c55c objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18c0304ac -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 228
3   UIKit                           0x1922d60a0 -[UITableView _existingCellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 160
4   UIKit                           0x1922e5cc4 -[UITableView _heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 160
5   UIKit                           0x1920dd6ac -[UISectionRowData heightForRow:inSection:canGuess:] + 280
6   UIKit                           0x1920dd3d4 -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 992
7   UIKit                           0x1920e06d8 -[UITableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:] + 164
8   UIKit                           0x1921ba020 -[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:] + 940
9   UIKit                           0x1921b9b2c -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 52
10  Ribony                          0x10008c730 0x10002c000 + 395056
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x18afdd1c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x18afea008 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 576
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x18aff6648 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x18afdf164 _dispatch_source_invoke + 820
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x18afe1bc0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 572
16  CoreFoundation                  0x18c101f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
17  CoreFoundation                  0x18c0ffb18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
18  CoreFoundation                  0x18c02e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
19  GraphicsServices                0x18dab1198 GSEventRunModal + 180
20  UIKit                           0x192008628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
21  UIKit                           0x192003360 UIApplicationMain + 208
22  Ribony                          0x100032fd8 0x10002c000 + 28632
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x18b0105b8 start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b122014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e9460 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018b0963f4 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018ab612d4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018ab7ecc0 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018ab8c844 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018ab7b66c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018ab7b6dc std::terminate() + 64
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018ab8c7a0 _destroyAltHandlerList + 0
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018afdd1d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018afea008 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 576
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018aff6648 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018afdf164 _dispatch_source_invoke + 820
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018afe1bc0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 572
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c101f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c0ffb18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c02e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
17  GraphicsServices                0x000000018dab1198 GSEventRunModal + 180
18  UIKit                           0x0000000192008628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
19  UIKit                           0x0000000192003360 UIApplicationMain + 208
20  Ribony                          0x0000000100032fd8 0x10002c000 + 28632
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018b0105b8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b122a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b122a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b10416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b103fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c101cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c0ff908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c02e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018cb3cb1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018cb5d60c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000019297dc7c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000018cc3a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7860 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7770 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  RLMRealm notification listener
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b108630 kevent + 8
1   Realm                           0x0000000100469890 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() (external_commit_helper.cpp:199)
2   Realm                           0x000000010046a950 std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0>::operator()() (future:2341)
3   Realm                           0x000000010046a8d8 std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::__execute() (future:1032)
4   Realm                           0x000000010046aaa0 std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >*> >(void*, void*) (memory:2525)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7860 _pthread_body + 240
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7770 _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  GAIThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b10416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b103fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c101cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c0ff908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c02e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018cb3cb1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018cb912a0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   Ribony                          0x00000001000f4484 0x10002c000 + 820356
8   Foundation                      0x000000018cc3a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7860 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7770 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b122a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b10416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b103fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c101cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c0ff908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c02e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a57d1fe8 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a57f7f14 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7860 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7770 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b10416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b103fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c101cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c0ff908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c02e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018c81bcec +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
6   Foundation                      0x000000018cc3a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7860 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7770 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b122a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b121e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e69d0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018ab113ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001908d6548 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 112
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001908d64bc bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 168
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001908d639c std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<std::__1::mutex, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::mutex> >::~__shared_ptr_emplace() + 0
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001908d664c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 92
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7860 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7770 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 14 name:  WebThread
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b10416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b103fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c101cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c0ff908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c02e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   WebCore                         0x0000000190bcfa2c RunWebThread(void*) + 456
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7860 _pthread_body + 240
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7770 _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 15 name:  JIT Worklist Worker Thread
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b121e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e69d0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018ab113ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001908bee6c WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 2016
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001906979b8 JSC::JITWorklist::runThread() + 192
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190697e08 WTF::Vector<WTF::RefPtr<JSC::JITWorklist::Plan>, 32ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>::expandCapacity(unsigned long, WTF::RefPtr<JSC::JITWorklist::Plan>*) + 0
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019000735c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019000726c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7860 _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7770 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 16 name:  WTF Parallel Helper Thread
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b121e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e69d0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018ab113ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001908bee6c WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 2016
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001908be464 WTF::ParallelHelperPool::waitForClientWithTask(WTF::Locker<WTF::LockBase> const&) + 288
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001908be204 WTF::ParallelHelperPool::helperThreadBody() + 76
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019000735c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019000726c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7860 _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e7770 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b1e4dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001702eb337
    x4: 0x000000018ab7fbc3   x5: 0x000000016fdd2660   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x000000018b0ad792  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b0fbec40  x21: 0x000000016fdd2660  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x00000001b0fbed20
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000010  x26: 0xffffffffffffffff  x27: 0x00000001b0fb9fc0
   x28: 0x0000000000001080   fp: 0x000000016fdd25c0   lr: 0x000000018b1e9460
    sp: 0x000000016fdd25a0   pc: 0x000000018b122014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

But i still don't know the where is the problem. Looks like i have a problem with tableview but i have too much tableviews in my app. So which tableview? Which file? Which line?

How to know them?

Comment: You haven't succeeded with symbolication, look at frame #10 which is from your App (Ribony) but it wasn't properly decoded. Fixing that should point to where the problem is in your code.

Comment: Hmm you look right. But i dont know what to do anymore for decode